# making multiple maven mirror repositories

Tags: java, maven-3, artifactory

I have set up an artifactory and made 3 repositories in it namely **A,B and C**. Now in my settings.xml file I have configured A to be a mirror of everything as:

```
<mirror>
      <id>myRepo</id>
      <name>remote repo</name>
      <url>http://<url>:<port>/artifactory/A</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf> 
</mirror>
```

Now each time I build , maven only looks for artifacts under A and not those under B or C . So is there a way to ensure that B and C are also looked up alongwith A?
I tried keeping multiple entries for mirror but since each would have same `<mirrorOf>` values so it wouldn't be picked up by Maven. I came across this : [Maven doc to mirror](http://people.apache.org/~ltheussl/maven-stage-site/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) and found that , "*A single mirror can handle multiple repositories when used in conjunction with a repository manager.*"
Since I am already using an artifactory with 3 repositories,  I can't figure out how to configure it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define [a virtual repository](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories), which will resolve to A, B and C and configure your mirror settings to this repository.
The simplest way to get your settings file right is just [to generate it](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Artifacts+Resolution) in Artifactory.

P.S. Please also note [the caveat](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Artifacts+Resolution#ConfiguringArtifactsResolution-AdditionalMirror-anySetup) when using mirror-any.